# Airflow 2.6.3 ValueError: filedescriptor out of range in select() error

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I have a sample airflow dag as show below:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.ssh.hooks.ssh import SSHHook
from airflow.providers.ssh.operators.ssh import SSHOperator
from airflow.operators.email import EmailOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator

default_args = {
    'owner': 'mpawa',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2023, 12, 2, 10, 0),
    'schedule_interval': '0 10 * * *',
    'retries': 3,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'catchup': False,
}
dag = DAG('mpawa_vintage_extraction', default_args=default_args)
sshHook = SSHHook(ssh_conn_id="sqream_prod", cmd_timeout=86400)


copy_alf_command = """
/home/bigdata/sqloader/tz/mpawa_scripts/Extract_ALF_File.sh
"""
copy_alf = SSHOperator(
    task_id='copy_alf',
    ssh_hook=sshHook,
    command=copy_alf_command,
    dag=dag)

# Define dependencies
copy_alf
```

When I run it I get the error below:

```
[2023-12-03, 01:39:10 EAT] {ssh.py:478} INFO - Running command: 
/home/bigdata/sqloader/tz/mpawa_scripts/Extract_ALF_File.sh
[2023-12-03, 01:39:10 EAT] {taskinstance.py:1824} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hadoop/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/providers/ssh/operators/ssh.py", line 173, in execute
    result = self.run_ssh_client_command(ssh_client, self.command, context=context)
  File "/home/hadoop/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/providers/ssh/operators/ssh.py", line 158, in run_ssh_client_command
    exit_status, agg_stdout, agg_stderr = self.ssh_hook.exec_ssh_client_command(
  File "/home/hadoop/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/providers/ssh/hooks/ssh.py", line 516, in exec_ssh_client_command
    readq, _, _ = select([channel], [], [], cmd_timeout)
ValueError: filedescriptor out of range in select()
[2023-12-03, 01:39:10 EAT] {taskinstance.py:1345} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=mpawa_vintage_extraction, task_id=copy_alf, execution_date=20231202T213039, start_date=20231202T223910, end_date=20231202T223910
[2023-12-03, 01:39:10 EAT] {standard_task_runner.py:104} ERROR - Failed to execute job 2583 for task copy_alf (filedescriptor out of range in select(); 120881)
[2023-12-03, 01:39:11 EAT] {local_task_job_runner.py:225} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
```

I have set parallelism = 100 in my airflow.cfg file and tried settting ulimit -n 8192 but the error has persisted.
I am using celery executor.

Kindly assist